# Ernie and the Lock-down Puzzle

Tags: geometry, construction, jigsaw-puzzle, paper-folding

During lock-down I was feeling a bit lost for something to do, so one one day I sent Ernie a text reading "**Bored**".

He responded with a text-less message and an attached image (see below).

I wasn't sure what it meant so I sent "**?**", to which he responded "**It's a puzzle!**".

It still wasn't obvious what I was meant to do, so I sent "**??**", and he responded "**Might need scissors, sellotape, a scalpel and a straight edge**". As I was digesting that, he added "**...or maybe tin-snips, drills, solder and a vice (depending on the materials you have in stock)**".

So I printed the image, pasted it to card and cut out the pieces. Then spent quite some time try to solve it. After getting nowhere for a few days I sent him another message "**???**",  to which he immediately replied "**Good grief - there are only ten pieces - It can't be that hard!**".

I have tried again off and on, but I'm still getting nowhere so thought I would ask for your help before I try and ask Ernie for any more hints. Any idea how to 'solve' the puzzle. Just what am I supposed to make with the pieces and how will I know when I have succeeded?

[image]

Comment: I think I know the answer and how to solve this, but unfortunately I don't have much time to *roll* it. Very nice puzzle! :)

Comment: I think you mean "vise", not "vice". :)

Comment: I'm never sure exactly what Ernie means. But good find.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ernie's jigsaw puzzle isn't as straightforward as it seems, as it's actually:

> a jigsaw puzzle for the **net of a die**.

One way of assembling the pieces legally is:

> [image]
>
>  This can then be folded into a three-dimensional cube along the bold lines shown.  (Additional thin-lined squares also provided to aid perceiving it in its fully folded state.)

How will you know when you have succeeded?

> When you can actually use it to play one of your favourite board games!
>
>  [image]

PS Ernie definitely has a sense of humour about him. After all, when you texted him with "Bored", he replied...

> ...with something for a **board** game! (pun)

Comment: Nail, head, hit...